# XAMPP centos uploaded files by PHP not shows up

Tags: php, centos, xampp

I am running `xampp 5.6.8` on `Centos 7` dedicated machine.
I developed Simple script to upload any file to the server via PHP on the machine, PHP code:

```
<?php
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'])) {
   echo "File ". $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'].'-'.$_FILES['uploadfile']["tmp_name"]." - uploaded successfully.<br>";
   echo disk_free_space('/');
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="uploadfile" type="file">
            <input name="sendfile" value="upload" type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i send a sample file echo returns:

> File sample.txt - /opt/lampp/temp/phpD58n0L - uploaded successfully.

Some information and facts:

- When i turn `xampp` on its running by `daemon` user
- `/opt/lampp/temp/` directory is belong to `daemon:daemon` by `chown command`
- `/opt/lampp/temp/` set to 770 permissions
- `php.ini` set to allow files up to 128mb and upload directory is `/opt/lampp/temp/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `is_uploaded_file()` just checks if it's an uploaded file or not. It's not going to move it anywhere from your /temp/ directory. You may want to have a look at the [manual on POST uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). Example:

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

That is, you should be using `move_uploaded_file()` to move the upload to where it belongs. Otherwise, says the manual, explaining why you don't find the files in your /temp/ directory:

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

The function [is_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) is a security check on the file's origin, and that's all it ever does. You can use it together with `move_uploaded_file()` for example like this:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) { 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $destination_file)) {
        // Was moved
    }
    else {
        // Wasn't moved
    }
else {
    // Wasn't valid
}
```

This may be redundant with regular file uploads-and-moves though, I notice in the comments at the manual that `move_uploaded_file()` would do that check in any case.